# Sequel Ace missing list of tables component

Tags: mysql, client

I am using Sequel Ace (version 4.0.13 on Mac) to access a database.  There used to be a list of all the tabels in the database in a component on the left side that is now missing.

I cannot figure out how to make that list of tables appear.  I've looked through the menu items but I can't find a way to bring this section back to the UI.

Any ideas?

Comment: Information_schema see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

Click on the left side where it used to be and drag to the right.

I just had and fixed this problem. I stumbled across this question when looking for the answer.